# Create/New DB record for each generated set of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have got a problem with saving multiple record.

This script wil load a list of instruments that belong to a department through a join table.
This form will make a new record for another join table, the problem is when I'f got 4 instruments it only will save the last instrument.

[Image generated list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9aD7.jpg)

Can anybody help me out to solve this problem or point me into the right direction ??

```
<%= form_for(:joindaylisting) do |j| %>
  <% @instrumentslist.each do |instrument| %>

    <tr class="<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">
      <td>
        <% j.label(:instrument_id, "#{instrument.name}") %>
        <%= link_to("#{instrument.name}", {:controller => 'instruments', :action => 'show_instruction', :instrument_id => instrument.id}, :onclick=>"window.open('height=670, width=675');return false;") %>
      </td>
      <%= j.hidden_field(:instrument_id, :value => instrument.id) %>

      <td></td>
      <% j.label(:ammountdesinfection, "") %>
      <td><%= j.text_field(:ammountdesinfection) %></td>
      <% j.label(:ammountinstruments, "") %>
      <td><%= j.text_field(:ammountinstruments) %></td>
      <% j.label(:ammountrelease, "") %>
      <td><%= j.text_field(:ammountrelease) %></td>
      <% j.label(:notes, "") %>
      <td><%= j.text_area(:notes) %></td>
    </tr>

    <% j.label(:department_id) %>
    <%= j.hidden_field(:department_id, :value => @department.id) %>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the last one is saved because the fields have the same name and the last one overrides all other values. See the params you are getting on the receiving controller.

You probably want/need to configure departments to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :instruments` and a form for the department object with `fields_for: instruments`. I've highlighted keywords that my help you get the information you want, the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the info Leito I'm going to study these pieces.